# Copy & pasting from tmux includes previous copies

Tags: tmux

I started using tmux a few months ago. I love it. One of the behaviours however that I can't seem to understand is as follows.

If I go into copy mode and copy a piece of text, it will copy it fine. My setup allows for it to be copied to my macOS clipboard just as fine.

When I copy and paste for a second, third, etc. time, however, previous excerpts that I copied would be part of the text I paste.

Can anybody explain this behavior to me and how I could fix it? It is my understanding that it's intended for tmux to aggregate copied text into a buffer, and that's fine. I just would like to paste single bits of text from time to time (search something on Google, or copying a URL).

Comment: You must be using something that appends to the clipboard rather than overwriting it. Post your `.tmuxrc` and any other applicable file, and tell us exactly which commands you use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Are you using Kitty terminal? It has a problem where it appends to the selection instead of replacing it. Does this still happen in Terminal.app or iTerm2?

2) Or are you using both `pbcopy` and `set-clipboard` to make tmux set the system clipboard? Try `set -s set-clipboard off` in `.tmux.conf` and restart tmux (`tmux kill-server`).

Comment: I _am_ using Kitty. Your comment helped me debug and now I was able to come up with a solution. 

Had to disable the clipboard and manually configure the copy behavior in `.tmux.conf` using `pbcopy`. Will answer below.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using kitty terminal you may use the following configuration on your `kitty.conf`

```
clipboard_control write-primary write-clipboard no-append
```

Comment: Yup, this solved it for me using tmux+nvim+popos

Answer (score 3):

@Nicholas Marriot provided insight that led me to this solution:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/564333/406997

In my case I ended up using `pbcopy` rather than `xsel`:

```
set -s set-clipboard off

bind-key -T copy-mode-vi v send-keys -X begin-selection
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi MouseDragEnd1Pane send -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "pbcopy"
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "pbcopy"
```

Comment: You can look at https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/Clipboard for more on this.